# Why is OnTriggerEnter not working in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh-collider

I am very new to unity, and this is probably going to seem like a dumb question to all the people who are good at C#, but I don't know why OnTriggerEnter is not working in this program. I have typed it as it said in the tutorial I'm following but it has no effect in the game. Help?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollisions : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know what to try.

Comment: The Rigidbody must be in at least one of the two colliding objects. Check if you have a rigid body.

Comment: I claim this is a **TYPO**: Your `OnTriggerEnter` is **nested** as a local method within the `Update` method ... This way Unity will not find it when invoking it via its messaging system. I vote to close this question as typo based as it will not really be helpful for others

Comment: Honestly the ability to created nested methods in .NET was a dark day indeed.

Comment: @derHugo I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @RedStone I do have a Rigidbody in one of the objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as you seem to have difficulty to understand what is happening here again.

In

```
void Update()
{
    // I am a local function within the Update method!
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

you have the `OnTriggerEnter` nested undert the `Update` method as a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). This way Unity doesn't "know"/find it when trying to invoke it via its messaging system.

You rather want to have it as a normal method on class level

```
void Update()
{

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

and now since `Update` and `Start` are empty it is actually best to remove them all along ;)

Comment: Thank you I'm really new to unity